# Python: how to search dictionary and copy values?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am a newbie user. I have two dictionaries ("rows" and "data").

```
rows[0]
{'created_at': 'Thu Apr 16 23:46:39 +0000 2015', 'userid': '129442364', 'long': '-86.220239', 'id': '5.89E+17', 'lat': '32.307761'}

data[0]
{'clong': -87.647638, 'tlong': -87.65853953, 'clat': 41.944175, 'tlat': 41.94704868, 'distance_km': 0.9568556041682102}
```

I would like to search "rows" and when I find that the values for both 'long' and 'lat' coincide with values for 'clong' and 'clat', I want to copy 'created_at' key from "rows" into "data".

```
for key in data.iteritems():
    if item["clong"] in rows[0]['long'] and item["clat"] in rows[0]['lat']:
        data["created_at"]= [rows['created_at']]
```

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work and I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `rows` and `data` probably aren't really dicts. The `[0]` is really suspicious.

Comment: `rows` and `data` look like lists of dicts (because you are accessing `rows[0]` and `lists[0]`). Plus, the `key` variable is never used in your loop, so it looks like you are accessing the first entry each time.

Comment: I think they are list of dicts?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Comment: *"the above code doesn't work"* is not a sufficient problem statement, what error does it give out or none at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The problem statement is **how to search dictionary and copy values?**, which is valid.  I agree *"the above code doesn't work"* with no error description is poor form, but the question is answerable.

Comment: Are those lists ordered? As in: do you only need to compare `rows[N]` to `data[N]` or search a matching entry in all `row` and `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The most direct (albeit less efficient) might be to iterate over `rows` and `data` and if there is a match of `long` & `lat` keys, add the `time` key of the current `row` to the `i`<sup>th</sup> element of `data`.

Or by example

```
rows = [
    {'long':1, 'lat':4, 'time': '7:00'},
    {'long':2, 'lat':5, 'time': '8:00'},
    {'long':3, 'lat':6, 'time': '9:00'}
]
data = [
    {'long':1,  'lat':4, },
    {'long':20, 'lat':5, },
    {'long':3,  'lat':6, }
]

for row in rows:
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        if row['long'] == d['long'] and row['lat'] == d['lat']:
           data[i]['time'] = row['time']

for x in data:
    print x
```

output

```
{'lat': 4, 'long': 1, 'time': '7:00'}
{'lat': 5, 'long': 20}
{'lat': 6, 'long': 3, 'time': '9:00'}
```

Notice the second element did not get the `time` key because the `lat`/`long` did not match.

Comment: To whoever gave the down vote, I welcome constructive criticism. Anything wrong? or should something be changed?